# Plot time series standard deviation in r

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I would like to plot the standard deviation of a time series as a shadow or as two dotted lines which embed the time series, but I can't find a solution.
I want to plot something like this (this is the actual data, but I've created a zoo object, and I want to work with that ts), where the red dotted lines represent the standard deviation.

Thanks in advance

[image]

This is an excerpt from dput(df)

```
structure(c(27.97, 27.95, 27.96, 27.95, 27.97, 27.98, 27.95, 
27.94, 27.92, 27.92, 27.9, 27.89, 27.88, 27.88, 27.87, 27.87, 
27.85, 27.86, 27.86, 27.84, 27.87, 27.87, 27.85, 27.86, 27.85, 
27.84, 27.82, 27.82, 27.83, 27.84, 27.83, 27.83, 27.83, 27.83, 
27.83, 27.83, 27.83, 27.82, 27.81, 27.8, 27.82, 27.82, 27.8, 
27.81, 27.78, 27.78, 27.81, 27.8, 27.81, 27.8, 27.79, 27.77, 
27.76, 27.76, 27.76, 27.76, 27.75, 27.72, 27.72, 27.72, 27.71, 
27.69, 27.71, 27.72, 27.72, 27.71, 27.71, 27.7, 27.71, 27.69, 
27.7, 27.67, 27.67, 27.66, 27.67, 27.66, 27.66, 27.68, 27.67, 
27.67, 27.65, 27.67, 27.66, 27.66, 27.64, 27.65, 27.66, 27.65, 
27.66, 27.63, 27.64, 27.6, 27.59, 27.57, 27.59, 27.59, 27.58)
,index = 1:4417, class = "zoo")
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(df)` into you post? `df` is your data frame.

Comment: Maybe this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022192/add-a-ribbon-to-a-line-plot-in-r?rq=1

Comment: It's a bit complicated, because my dataset contains temperature measured every 5 seconds for 6 hours (approximately 4400 rows).

Comment: You can post a subset of your data set, let us say, `dput(head(df, 20))`

Comment: @aipam did you get to trying the solution code I pasted below?

Comment: @onlyphantom Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with `zoo` and not use a `ggplot` implementation, the vanilla `lines()` seem to do what you want quite well.

In the code below `k1` is a `zoo` object I created from your `dput`.

```
plot.ts(k1, ylim=c(27.5, 28.5)) 
lines(k1+1*sd(k1), lwd=0.6, lty=2)
lines(k1-1*sd(k1), lwd=0.6, lty=2)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Note that zoo supports ggplot2 using `autoplot.zoo` so it's not an either/or.

Comment: good info @G.Grothendieck thanks for mentioning that too; I am inclined to say "ggplot supports zoo" rather than the other way: "zoo supports ggplot" though, but nevertheless good point

Comment: ggplot2 does not have any code that specifically supports zoo but zoo has quite a bit of code that specifically supports ggplot2 including autoplot.zoo, fortify.zoo, facet_free, yearmon_trans, scale_x_yearmon, scale_y_yearmon, yearqtr_trans, scale_x_yearqtr, scale_y_yearqtr